# How to implement language packs in PHP

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, if-statement, language-packs

I created 3 language packs for my site: English, Spanish and French. I am just having trouble implementing them based on user selection. I have the following drop down menu:

> ```
> <select onchange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
>   <option>Select</option>
>   <option value="?lang=eng">US English</option>
>   <option value="?lang=esp">Español</option>
>     <option value="?lang=fra">Français</option>
> </select>
> ```

How can I include the language files based on what the user selects, I just don't know what to put as the **condition** in the **if statement**.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What condition do you want to check against?

Comment: You might be better converting your `<option>Select</option>` to an `<optgroup>` - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: Title/tag definitely missleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, save the value that the user selected in the user session. e.g.:

```
switch($_POST['lang']) {
    case 'en': $_SESSION['lang'] = 'English'; break;
    case 'sp': $_SESSION['lang'] = 'Spanish'; break;
    default:   $_SESSION['lang'] = 'English'; break;
}
```

On every page request, fetch the language files from the relevant language folder according to the value the you saved.

For example, this how will look the files structure:

- English

  - Global.php
  - Register.php
- Spanish

  - Global.php
  - Register.php

Then, whenever you need to load a text file, use:

```
function load_text_file($filename) {
    include 'languages/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '/' . $filename.'php';
    return $txt;    // $txt should be an array
}
//...
```

$text = array();
$text += load_text_file('Global');
$text += load_text_file('Register');

Answer (score 2):

As you're bringing in the option via a query string, you can access it with

```
$lang = $_GET['lang']
```

Comment: Just a note: you'd probably have to do a little more work in the actual application, such as validate the value and make it English by default. But I suppose that's not part of the OP's question so +1.

Answer (score 0):

For my template, that piece of code is

`$_SESSION['language'] = 'english';`